# Reduce or heighten a DTM with overlaying polygons

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis-3

[image]
I am using QGIS 3.01.

I have a DTM over a historic area. There has been done archaeological surveys there, which suggest that the ground was several meteres below todays surface many hundred years ago.

I was wondering if there is a tool or a method in QGIS to reduce/increase the height of certain areas in the raster based on values from polygons?

Like in the attached picture, with a attribute for meters that the raster calculator could do computations on or something?

Comment: rasterize your polygons with the attribute value and then raster calculator?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question. You can always ask about the other one in a separate question, and that way you'll be able to provide details of what you have tried with each.